# KModes : initialize centroids with an array and categorical data

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I am trying to reproduce the results of a KModes clustering model initially started at 'random'.
For that I try to initialize the centroids with the array of previous centroids.
It seems that the model doesnt recognize categorical data.
What would be the right syntax to use an array to initiate the centroids?

Code:

```
att1 = [1,2,3,1,1,2,3,1]  
att2 = ['A','B','B','A','C','C','C','C']  
data1 = list(zip(att1, att2))  
test = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns =['A1','A2'])  


kmodeTest = KModes(n_clusters=3, init = 'random', n_init = 3, verbose=1).fit(test)  

cent = kmodeTest.cluster_centroids_
```

The centroids results is:

array([['1', 'C'], ['1', 'A'], ['2', 'B']], dtype='<U11')

If I use it to create a similar clustering:

```
kmodeTest2 = KModes(n_clusters=3, init = cent, n_init = 3, verbose=1).fit(test)
```

I have the Error message:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'C'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an encoded array for clusters centroids.
The syntax is:

```
cent = kmodeTest._enc_cluster_centroids
```